# tFileInputDelimited Override repository sourced filename

Tags: talend

I have many file formats specified in the metadata repository and want to use these in my tFileInputDelimited components.

However the filename changes daily so differs from what was used to initially create the repository metadata schema. In the tFileInputDelimited, if I use Property Type "Built-In" it appears I can set the filename but then can't use the repository's field & row separator. If I use property Type "Repository", then I get the row and field separators but can't override the filename.

How can I use the Row Separator and Field Separator from the repository metadata but override the filename for a tFileInputDelimited?

Comment: it doesnt look that you can define a context.pathname while creating repository metadata for file delimited. For your usecase i would be inclined to use built-in and to create a new context.Filenamewithfullpath to store your file path and use this context in your tFileInputDelimited filename/stream settings. Its clear that with this way you can not refer to repository field and row separators in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `export as context` button in the metadata editor and then set the context variable with a tJava component on your main workflow.